# Retrieve Email in windows form using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, email, gmail, yahoo

I know this question has been asked many times, but i did not find any good answers. How to retrieve email from any one of the following servers(**gmail**, **yahoo**, **hotmail**). I need to read those messages in windows form itself. **OpenPop** and one more ddl files I have used, but there is no accuracy or i didn't find the correct way to use it. Can anyone tell, is there any other ddl files available? And give example code. 
  I have used (**OpenPop.dll**). Here is my code :

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Connect("pop.mail.yahoo.com", 995,true);
            client.Authenticate("username", "Password");
            int messagecount = client.GetMessageCount();
            List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messagecount);
            for (int i = messagecount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
            }

             s = allMessages.ToString();

             foreach (var msg in allMessages)
             {
                 MessagePart plainText = msg.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
                 if (plainText != null)
                 {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(plainText);
                 }
             }


        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DLL have you used? are you getting any errors?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."